# Backbone Event Triggering a Popup getting blocked.

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, click

I'm having an issue where I want to call GET on an endpoint, and based on the result of that, either render a modal or follow a link.

Currently, when I get the click event, I disable the default behavior of the anchor tag (I don't want to redirect before I check the result.).
 I do a GET on the endpoint and throw an event from the callback if one of the return parameters is true.  This event has a listener on it that
 will trigger rendering and displaying the modal.

The issue with this methodology is: The GET callback doesn't allow me to redirect to the link unless I disable popup blockers and I would like my 
 users to have a good user experience.

I'm debating between a polling strategy (non-performant, not always accurate) or having the click event open a window that will either follow the anchor tag
 or render the modal.

Would appreciate any other ideas or suggestions.  Thanks!

Template is defined as follows:

```
var template = _.template('\
  <a href="<%-linkUrl%>?fromHome=true" draggable="false" data-type="app-button" data-se="app-button" target="_blank" \
    class="app-button">\
    <img draggable="false" src="<%-logoUrl%>" class="logo">\
    <span data-action="show-settings" class="icon-button <%-showIcon%>">\
      <span class="icon icon-settings-dark"></span>\
    </span>\
  </a>\
<p class="app-button-name" data-se="app-button-name"><%-label%></p>\
');
```

Events are defined as follows:

```
events: function () {
  var events = {};
  events['click [data-type=app-button]'] = '_firstLoginSettings';

  return events;
},
```

Now here's the function itself being called.

```
_firstLoginSettings: function (e) {
  if (this.model.get('__notVerified__')) {
    this.state.trigger(Events.SHOW_CONFIRMATION, this.model);
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.state.trigger(Events.CHECK_VPN_DIALOG, this.model);
  }
},
```

I have a listener on my main router.

```
  this.listenTo(this.state, Events.CHECK_VPN_DIALOG, this._checkVpnDialog);
```

And here's the rest of the router code:

```
_checkVpnDialog: function (appLink, appLinkSettings) {
  var self = this;
  var vpnSettings = new VpnSettings({
    appLink: appLink,
    '__appInstanceId__' : appLink.get('__appInstanceId__')
  });
  vpnSettings.fetch({}).done(_.bind(function(vpnSettings) {
    if (vpnSettings.checkVpn) {
      self.state.trigger(Events.SHOW_VPN_DIALOG, appLink);
    } else {
      appLink._firstLoginSettings();
      //This doesn't work because it's not associated with a user action, so it won't let me open this window.  This isn't part of the click event loop any more.
      var linkUrlTemplate = _.template('<%-linkUrl%>?fromHome=true');
      window.open(linkUrlTemplate({linkUrl: appLink.get('__linkUrl__')}));
    }

  }));
},

_showVpnDialog: function (appLink, appLinkSettings) {
  this.credsDialog && this.credsDialog.remove();
  if (!appLinkSettings) {
    appLinkSettings = new AppLinkSettings({
      id: appLink.get('id'),
      '__tab__': appLink.get('__tab__')
    });
    appLinkSettings.fetch().done(_.bind(this._renderVpnDialog, this, appLink, appLinkSettings));
  } else {
    this._renderVpnDialog(appLink, appLinkSettings);
  }
},

_renderVpnDialog: function (appLink, appLinkSettings) {
  if (appLink.get('__needsVpn__')) {
    this.vpnDialog = new VpnDialog({
      model: appLink,
      appLink: appLink,
      settings: this.settings,
      state: this.state
    });
    this.vpnDialog.render();
  }
},
```

Comment: Browsers will block popups without direct **synchronous** interaction from the user (e.g. a click event). By making an asynchronous XHR before opening the popup you are breaking that rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did instead was to open a new window with the click, and then change the location of the window so it would either go to the new location or close itself.  Kind of a hacky solution, but it works!